# Python List Comprehension: If Item Doesn't Exist, Insert a Value?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists which i want to merge together as two separate arrays into one dataframe. The issue is, the data i am working with is patchy and has missing information

**Data**

[image: Data]

**Create 3 Lists**

```
Name = [item[0] for item in Data if item]
Age = [item[1] for item in Data if item]
Fruit = [item[2] for item in Data if item]
```

Which produces:

```
Name = ['John', 'Eric', 'Dave', 'Mike', 'Charlotte']
Age = ['32', '25', '31']
Fruit = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear']
```

However, this clearly causes an error when trying to `pd.DataFrame` as the lists are not the same length.

Is there a way i can improve my list comprehension to insert a blank or default value to ensure my lists remain the same length, resulting in something like:

```
Name = ['John', 'Eric', 'Dave', 'Mike', 'Charlotte']
Age = ['32', '', '25', '31', '']
Fruit = ['', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', '']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: What exactly is `Data`? Please provide a reproducible object (as code)

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks! I simplified my example, some of the lists are empty. Any idea why this causes a syntax error?

item[4] for item in data if len(item)>3 else ''

Comment: That should be `[item[4] if len(item) > 3 else '' for item in data]`

Comment: `print(Data)`. There are a number of problems with your "snippet". First: don't ask in a comment, then, you're missing the square brackets, also ***d**ata*, then reverse the keywords ....

Comment: you can add extra blanks, but while aligning, it adds at the end of the lists. The problem starts with creating 3 lists without the correct place of blanks (''). How do you know that first item of the Fruit is blank (or second item of Age is blank)?

Comment: What is the `Data`? as mozway said please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to wrap my head around how your `Data` is represented. Because, if 2nd-row(`Data[1]`) did not have anything at index `1`, then your code should have produced

```py
Age = ["Apple", 25, 31]
```

Then an IndexError as there wasn't anything on the last row's 2nd column. This means some kind of placeholder is there to indicate the empty slot. Thus you can check equivalency for that value and assign values accordingly.

Given the placeholder is `None`, you can do the following...

```py
Name = [ (i[2] if i[2] is not None else "") for i in Data ]
```

In case, each sub-array pre-processing is not of same length, that is does not have any values *(I'm still confused how you didn't get IndexError on last line for `Fruit`-comprehension)*, you can fill it up with None and then use the above method.